# Maven adding dependencies not in pom file

Tags: maven

I am defining a module with only two dependencies in the pom file, but the generated .classpath file(using mvn eclipse:eclipse) contains other dependencies also.

I checked the dependencies of the modules added in this pom, but not all of them were added.

So the scenario is:

- Project A depends on Project B
- Project B depends on Projects X, Y and
  Z

When I run mvn eclipse:eclipse on Project A, the .classpath file contains Project B and Projects X and Y, but not Z.

This is not causing any problems, but is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour. Project B needs X, Y and Z to work properly, so these dependencies (called **transitive dependencies**) are effectively part of your project.

See [**this**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for a detailed explanation of maven dependency resolution.

You can call `mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn dependency:list` from command line to see all dependencies, including the transitive ones.

If you know that you are depending on an artifact, but it will be available at runtime, like it is the case with Java EE libraries on an application server, you can mark them as `provided` in your `pom`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>group</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

These dependencies will not be included in your resulting atrifact.

**EDIT:** please excuse my poor reading skills :) I have overseen the 'not' before the 'Z'.

This may still be normal behaviour if the dependency for Z is defined as `provided` or the `optional` flag is set to `true`, or if it is excluded. See [**this**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) for maven's handling of optional and excluded dependencies.

If neither of these options applies, then I would expect Z to be there with the other dependencies. The best way to check would be to run `mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn dependency:list` and grep the output for Z.

Comment: But the issue here is the classpath of Project A does not contain all the dependencies of Project B.

Comment: @cmn oops, sorry, my bad. Please see the edit. Is Z listed when you call `mvn dependency:tree`?